# How to create documentation header for a Object<CustomObject> return type in method c#

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm trying to create a documentation response header in a method like this

```cs
public Task<CustomObject> AuthUserAsync()
{
}
```

So, as I understand it should be something like

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Description.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/><<see cref="CustomObject"/>> representing the operation.</returns>
public Task<CustomObject> AuthUserAsync()
{
}
```

But I'm unable to see the documentation when hover the mouse on the method

Any ideas?

Comment: It's invalid XML. You have an extra set of angle brackets around your second `see` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax to use a template argument in a documentation header is:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Description.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A <see cref="Task{TResult}"/> representing the operation.</returns>
public Task<CustomObject> AuthUserAsync()
{
}
```

Note that the angle brackets are replaced by `{}`, because angle brackets would make the XML invalid at that point. You cannot put `Task{int}` there, even though that would be more exact, because `Task<int>` is not a type you can create a reference to. If you write it without the `cref`, you can do

```
/// <returns>A Task&gt;int&lt; representing the operation.</returns>
```

You are still not allowed to use literal `<` or `>` characters, though.